# echo a string while waiting on candump command to receive data

Tags: linux, bash

How to echo a string while waiting on CAN messages in a bash command candump

usually after running candump can0, it will wait for messages to run from the terminals. When it detects can0 in the messages it echo "True". I also want to echo "False" when there are no messages coming through, but since there is actually nothing outputting, it never outputs false. Is there a better solution?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
if candump can0 | grep -q 'can0'; then
  echo "True"
else
  echo "False"
fi
done
```

Comment: Use the `-T` and/or `-n` options to specify that `candump` should terminate after some time or number of messages.

Comment: I tried to use the -T to terminate after 5 minutes. it never terminates for some reasons

Answer (score 0):

so the candump can0 is a while loop and it will keep the the first if statement running forever. Solution is to add a timeout to the candump like that

```
if timeout 2s candump can0 | grep -q 'can0'; then
  echo "True"
```